# Better approaches to maintain audit for tables in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, audit

We have a production database using Change Data Capture(CDC) feature to maintain audit data for few tables. But because of the performance impacts and need to make changes to database structure like adding indexes which we can’t do due to CDC, we now want to disable CDC.

Requirement is to capture all the Insert, Delete and Update actions from web application for a set of tables in a single audit table. 
Let's take for example I have to maintain Audit information for TableA in TableB for each Add, Update and Remove done to TableA through web application [in C#].

I'm currently updating each stored procedure which can cause either of these 3 actions for each of the table in the set. But it's too error prone and time taking method as I have huge list of tables.

Please help with a better way which can be more efficient both in terms of time and performance to achieve this.

Comment: capture all the Insert, Delete and Update actions means triggers. To take ideas: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx

Comment: I don't think i can use triggers because there are batch processes also which update these tables and we don't want to audit information by them. Only actions through web application are required to be audited.

Comment: I don't know about CDC, but maybe using a repository pattern or unit of work after the insert/update/delete in the table (in the webapp) you can insert in the audit table or you can use AOP after the insert/update/delete of the table, and you can do it Async (Background task) and it won't block the "flow" of the webapp request...

Comment: Then execute another insert command which inserts data to your audit table whenever a user uses a control on your webpage which affects your database. 
IE: you have a button that saves the changes a user has made. After the update command has been executed, run another insert command to the audit table that you have.

Comment: In this case, I vote to close your question. We have not X-ray to see your C# application internals: it use stored procedures to manage data? It use EF? ADO? dbcontext? What is your CRUD pattern? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer : Just make sure that all actions that will change the DATABASE is recorded!

In our project, we created a separate table which has the Following Fields

```
   Date_And_Time     Actions     UserID     Part_of_Program
```

whenever a user executes an insert, update or delete command, or logs in or out of the system, or the system runs an automatic operation inside our database, the program automatically inserts a record here which tells us what action was taken, who did it and what what part of the program was affected.

..Or
you could write code that constantly checks the current size of your tables. If the size changes, then record it in the audit table. 
If the size increases, then data was inserted. otherwise data was deleted.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to design his audit table, he needs advise how to capture all the relevant events (i.e. update, insert, delete from his web app).

Comment: well, isn't these events triggered when a user uses a control on his system? Then have him execute another command that inserts data to his audit table whenever a control that executes a relevant event on his webapp.

Comment: He wrote in a comment that he cannot use triggers because they run batch operations that they don't want to see in the audit table.

Comment: Then don't execute an insert to the Audit table if it's a control/trigger that runs these batch processes.

Comment: @Malky.Kid many thanks for the advise but with your approach i'll have to make changes throughout data-access layer and in case I need to capture information for say 100-150 tables it's will mean a huge change across application and in production system i doubt this will be wise decision to go with.

Comment: Well, can't we create a function that can be called whenever a trigger has been changed in the access layer and simply change this function's parameters? otherwise, I have an other answer on my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry I simply can't see this done without using controls/triggers or without utilizing stored procedures. 
perhaps SQL server has an internal audit that you can utilize.(see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: In this case, I vote to close your question. We have not X-ray to see your C# application internals: it use stored procedures to manage data? It use EF? ADO? dbcontext? What is your CRUD pattern? etc.